# Discrepancy in solution file

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

we have recently updated VS/TFS within our team and everytime I open VS now, following warning message appears:

> "There appears to be a discrepancy between the solution's source
>   control information about some project(s) and the information in the
>   project file(s)"

When I do check-in, I get a change in .sln file for

```
SccTeamFoundationServer = http://czphaptfs01:8080/tfs
```

instead of

`SccTeamFoundationServer = http://czphaptfs01:8080/tfs/defaultcollection`.

I've tried to fix the file manully via Notepad but again, everytime I try to check-in something, the .sln is overwritten back. That leads me to a conclusion there might be possible something wrong set in VS, however when I double check TFS Team Connection in Manager Connection, everything appears fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the issue by reconnecting to the project in Team Explorer.